# Django - Fetching foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys, deferred-query

Model `A` has a `ForeignKey` to model `B` - I would like to fetch `A` instances and compare them to each other where the key to `B` is one of the comparison parameters.

Django defers fetching `B` related info, so if I want to optimize my code and fetch in advance the info I need I can do one of the following:

- Use `.select_related('B')` - which will fetch all related `B` instances
- Use `.select_related('B__id')` - which will fetch only the ids of all related `B` instances

AFAIK both require a join, where all I really needed was `A.B_id` which is a column in the database, as that is all I wanted to compare.

Am I missing something straightforward here?What am I missing here? Can I fetch `A.B_id` directly? Is

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your assertion is wrong: `select_related('B__id')` doesn't do anything. The double-underscore in a select_related call is only for following subsequent joins: so if B had a ForeignKey to C, `select_related('B__C')` would follow the second JOIN as well.

Secondly, I'm confused by your optimisation requirement. As you say, you just want `B_id`: so no JOIN is required, and neither is any optimisation. If you just get your A objects in the normal way, you can refer to the `b_id` field on each of them directly:

```
a_objects = A.objects.all()
for obj in a_objects:
    print a.b_id
```

Here only a single db call is made, with no JOINs.